# Formatting Data Labels on a Chart

Tags: excel, vba

I have written this which deletes every 3 out of 4 data labels so it is easier to read. I would like it though to cycle through all the charts in my workbook and also format the position of the datalabel so it is slightly above the line graph. Thanks

```
Sub ChartTest()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
    z = 1
    With ActiveChart
     If .ChartType = xlLine Then
        i = .SeriesCollection(1).Points.Count
        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Select
        For pts = 1 To i
            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(pts).HasDataLabel = True ' Make sure all points are visible data labels
        Next pts
        
        For pts = 1 To i
             ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(pts).DataLabel.Delete
            z = z + 1
            If z = 4 Then
                z = 1
                pts = pts + 1
           End If
            If pts = i Or pts = 1 Then ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Points(pts).HasDataLabel = True ' First & Last point in graph to have a label
        Next pts
    End If
   End With
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I decided on this after some hunting around...

```
Sub LabelLineGraphs()
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim cht As ChartObject

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet

    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each cht In sht.ChartObjects
            cht.Activate
            For x = 1 To ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection.Count ' Work through each series
                z = 1
                With ActiveChart
                    If .ChartType = xlLine Then
                        i = .SeriesCollection(x).Points.Count
                        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).DataLabels.Select
        
                        For pts = 1 To i
        
                            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).HasDataLabel = True ' Make sure all points are visible data labels
            
                            If x Mod 2 = 0 Then  ' Modify label position for each series so they are not in the same place
                                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Top = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).Top - 10 - (x * 5)
                                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Left = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).Left - 10 - (x * 5)
                            Else
                                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Top = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).Top + 10 + (x * 5)
                                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Left = ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).Left + 10 + (x * 5)
                            End If
  
                            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Font.Size = 8
                            If pts = i Then ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Top = 15
                            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.NumberFormat = "0.00%" ' will need to manually adjust time formats after
                        Next pts
        
                        For pts = 1 To i
                            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Select
                            ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).DataLabel.Delete
                            z = z + 1
                            If z = 4 Then
                                z = 1
                                pts = pts + 1
                            End If
                            
                            If pts = i Or pts = 1 Then ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(x).Points(pts).HasDataLabel = True ' First Last point in graph to have a label
                        Next pts
                    End If
                End With
            Next x
        Next cht
    Next sht

    CurrentSheet.Activate
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```